# A form isn't working when showing mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to set a mobile view for my site.
In this particular case i have to show two different forms according to the width of the page (under 400px it shows the "login-form-mobile").
The form submit is handled by a js function, the problem is that the function works only on the first form (over 400px), the second one submit without checking if inputs are empty etc...
Does someone knows why?

```js
function validaReg() {
  if (document.formregistrazione.nome.value === "") {
    togglediv("invalidname");
    invalidForm("nome");
    return false;
  }

  if (document.formregistrazione.email.value === "") {
    togglediv("invalidemail");
    invalidForm("email");
    return false;
  }

  if (document.formregistrazione.username.value === "") {
    togglediv("invalidusername");
    invalidForm("username");
    return false;
  }

  if (document.formregistrazione.password.value === "") {
    togglediv("invalidpassword");
    invalidForm("password");
    return false;
  }

  if (document.formregistrazione.ripeti_password.value === "") {
    togglediv("invalidrippassword");
    invalidForm("ripeti_password");
    return false;
  }

  var pw1 = document.getElementById("password");
  var pw2 = document.getElementById("ripeti_password");
  var id = document.getElementById("invalidrippassword");
  if (pw2.value != pw1.value) {
    pw2.classList.add("is-invalid");
    id.style.display = 'block';
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<div id="login-form" class="container-form fade-in-image">
  <div class="fade-in-image col-md-12 mb-3">
    <img id="logo" class="img-fluid" src="Fubles.png">
    <img id="logo-mobile" class="img-fluid" src="Fubles-mobile.png">
  </div>

  <form class="ctr-form" style="width:50%;" method="post" name="formregistrazione" onSubmit="return validaReg();" action="checkReg.php">
    <div>
      <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
          <label for="nome">Nome</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="inputname" placeholder="Name" onChange="retogglediv('invalidname'); retogglediv2('nome');">
          <div id="invalidname" class="invalid-feedback" style="display: none;">
            Inserire un nome
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
          <label for="cognome">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="inputemail" placeholder="Email" onChange="retogglediv('invalidemail'); retogglediv2('email');">
          <div id="invalidemail" class="invalid-feedback" style="display: none;">
            Inserire una email
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend3">@</span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="inputusername" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend3" onChange="retogglediv('invalidusername'); retogglediv2('username');">
            <div id="invalidusername" class="invalid-feedback" style="display: none;">
              Scegli un username
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
          <label for="stato">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="inputpassword" placeholder="Password" onChange="retogglediv('invalidpassword'); retogglediv2('password');">
          <div id="invalidpassword" class="invalid-feedback" style="display: none;">
            Scegli una password
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
          <label for="cap">Ripeti password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="ripeti_password" placeholder="Password" onChange="retogglediv('invalidrippassword'); retogglediv2('ripeti_password');">
          <div id="invalidrippassword" class="invalid-feedback" style="display: none;">
            La password deve corrispondere!
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" id="male" name="sex" value="M" class="custom-control-input" checked>
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="male">Uomo</label>
          </div>
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" id="female" name="sex" value="F" class="custom-control-input">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="female">Donna</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
          <button class="btn btn-signup justify-content-md-center" name="submit" type="submit">Registrati</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div style="overflow-y: scroll; margin-top: 5%;" id="login-form-mobile" class="container-form fade-in-image">
  <div class="fade-in-image col-md-12 mb-3">
    <img id="logo" class="img-fluid" src="Fubles.png">
    <img id="logo-mobile" class="img-fluid" src="Fubles-mobile.png">
  </div>

  <form method="post" name="formregistrazione" onSubmit="return validaReg();" action="checkReg.php">
    <div>
      <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
          <label for="nome">Nome</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="inputname" placeholder="Name" onChange="retogglediv('invalidname'); retogglediv2('nome');">
          <div id="invalidname" class="invalid-feedback" style="display: none;">
            Inserire un nome
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
          <label for="cognome">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="inputemail" placeholder="Email" onChange="retogglediv('invalidemail'); retogglediv2('email');">
          <div id="invalidemail" class="invalid-feedback" style="display: none;">
            Inserire una email
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend3">@</span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="inputusername" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend3" onChange="retogglediv('invalidusername'); retogglediv2('username');">
            <div id="invalidusername" class="invalid-feedback" style="display: none;">
              Scegli un username
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
          <label for="stato">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="inputpassword" placeholder="Password" onChange="retogglediv('invalidpassword'); retogglediv2('password');">
          <div id="invalidpassword" class="invalid-feedback" style="display: none;">
            Scegli una password
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
          <label for="cap">Ripeti password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="ripeti_password" placeholder="Password" onChange="retogglediv('invalidrippassword'); retogglediv2('ripeti_password');">
          <div id="invalidrippassword" class="invalid-feedback" style="display: none;">
            La password deve corrispondere!
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" id="male" name="sex" value="M" class="custom-control-input" checked>
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="male">Uomo</label>
          </div>
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" id="female" name="sex" value="F" class="custom-control-input">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="female">Donna</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
          <button class="btn btn-signup justify-content-md-center" name="submit" type="submit">Registrati</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is not working because you have a bug in the lines that start with `document.formregistrazione.` You are trying to read a `value` from `undefined`. Instead you can access your field value like this `document.formregistrazione["0"]["0"].value`.

Note: if you are trying to test the second form replace `document.formregistrazione["0"]["0"].value` by `document.formregistrazione["1"]["0"].value`! (Replace the first "0" by "1")

```
function validaReg() {
    console.log(document.formregistrazione);
    if (document.formregistrazione["0"]["0"].value === "") {
        togglediv("invalidname");
        invalidForm("nome");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.formregistrazione["0"]["1"].value === "") {
        togglediv("invalidemail");
        invalidForm("email");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.formregistrazione["0"]["2"].value === "") {
        togglediv("invalidusername");
        invalidForm("username");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.formregistrazione["0"]["3"].value === "") {
        togglediv("invalidpassword");
        invalidForm("password");
        return false;
    }
    if (document.formregistrazione["0"]["4"].value === "") {
        togglediv("invalidrippassword");
        invalidForm("ripeti_password");
        return false;
    }
    var pw1 = document.getElementById("password");
    var pw2 = document.getElementById("ripeti_password");
    var id = document.getElementById("invalidrippassword");
    if (pw2.value != pw1.value) {
        pw2.classList.add("is-invalid");
        id.style.display = 'block';
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The form works only for the first form, even if i replace the first 0 with 1, it works only on "login-form". Btw now it doesn't submit, just doesn't do anything on the second form

Comment: Could you comment on the first form and test the second one, the issue here is that you are using IDS 2 times, IDS should be unique.

Comment: Soufiane is right, the problem is that ids are repeating, i changed all the repeated ids and now it works

Comment: Great, could you please check the answer to help others.